# How to hide DataBase Field in Crystal Report On Condition

Tags: c#, sql-server, crystal-reports

Mostly I used RDLC Report,
in which if i want to Hide any field
In Visibility.Hidden property i write expression for it like this

```
 =IIf((Fields!SetBarcode1.Value="NOT APPLICABLE"), True,False)
```

Similarly how can i hide any database field which i drag and drop into my Crystal Report,

For Example my field name is TAG11 if it has "Not Applicable" in it during run time it should be hidden else show.

by searching on google i found that i have to write expression
by right click on field =>Choose Formate object => On Common Tab I found Supress if Duplicated option i should write Expression in it,
But i am not getting how.. i dont know syntax of Expression

i have this Report

[image]

on value 11 I give this Formula

[image]

but its not working  Report Shows like

[image]

Comment: are you using a text object and insert the object field inside??

Comment: NA. I Simply Drag And Drop it from Field Explorer, Check I my Second Image carefully.

Comment: i can`t seem to find the Suppress property, you need the suppress only

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Insert this formula :

```
{dtTotalProduction.Value11} = "NOT APPLICABLE"
```

and check the suppress property **not** suppress if duplicate

Comment: @VARUNNAYAK, Check the Suppress property NOT the Suppress If Duplicated.

Comment: One ,more Question, if I remove Box and Line just Put All Filed side by side, So if any of One Hidden How can I suppress that portion,
If you know Kindly Answer me on my this Question
[Link]
(http://stackoverflow.com/questions/24306287/how-to-supress-blank-space-in-crystal-report )

Comment: Suppress Blank Sections

Answer (score 0):

You can do the same in crystal aswell.

Instead of supress duplicate you need to write in only `Supress` option. click on `x-2` of the supress option there you can write your condition.

```
IIf((Fields!SetBarcode1.Value="NOT APPLICABLE"), True,False)
```

Answer (score 0):

I got it as  per @Siva Suggest me,
Instead of suppress duplicate I write in only Suppress option. click on x-2 of the suppress option where I  write this condition.

```
{dtTotalProduction.Value11} = "Not Applicable"
```

And Its Work Perfectly !!