# How to Supress Blank Space In Crystal report

Tags: c#, crystal-reports

I have Crystal Repot Like this :

[image]

In this I dynamically Supress Field as I I found Null value for that field,
But In Report It shows Blank Space Like here I am Hiding, tag0 ,tag1, tag11, value0 ,value1 ,value11 etc

So Report Shows Like this

[image]

I want to Remove this blank Space between Field, above  and Below I try
Section Expert => And Tick On Suppress Blank Section , but its not Working

As per Siva Suggest me i Can not Put All the tag in Different Section Because there are in Group Section not in Details
[image]

Here Field TAG 0 to 11 and Value 0 to 11 are Variables , which may be hidden or Visible Depend on User Selection , where other Field are static

Comment: Possible duplicate? Check if [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5974589/crystal-reports-suppressed-section-still-leaves-blank-spot) solution works out for you

Comment: are tag1, tag2... are in saperate sections? I mean line detaila, detailb etc?

Comment: @Siva All the Tag and Value Are In Same Section Detail-a

Answer (score 0):

Try the following step

= > Open your section expert (right click on some white space, you should see it come up).

= > Go to the options for the group footer and turn on reset page numbers after. You should see the page numbers reset at the beginning of each report.

= > Also in the section expert, go to the options for the page header and click on the blue    button next to the Suppress (No Drill-Down) option.

= > In the Formula Editor, enter PageNumber=1

Answer (score 0):

I would suggest you to place one tag in one details section like

```
tag1 in detaila
tag2 in detailb and so on
```

Then supress the section insetad of supressing the individual fields then you won't get this blank space.

Comment: Siva this Will work if my all field in Details Section But there are in Group section, Check My Question I updated It, and Add Image in it also.
So if I add another Group Section For each Field , it will effect field which are in Detail section

Comment: Though those are in group section you can add as group headera, groupheaderb etc.....try

Answer (score 0):

Right Click on the section >> Section Expert >> Check Suppress Blank Section

Comment: @VARUNNAYAK Check Reserve Minimum Page Footer

Comment: @abdularahman I didnt Found that option, where its located ??

Comment: @VARUNNAYAK right click on the section itselef section page(Footer)